How to prove that the solution to a linear ODE is always the zsr solution + the zir solution?
We've received this as a HW exercise in signal processing and I have no idea where to start.
The ODE we're talking about is $$\sum_{n=0}^{N}a_{n}\cdot y^{\left(n\right)}\left(t\right)=\sum_{m=0}^{M}b_{m}\cdot x^{\left(m\right)}\left(t\right)$$
And we need to show that the solution \$y(t)\$ is equal to: $$y(t)=y_{\text{zsr}}(t)+y_{\text{zir}}(t)$$
I'm really stuck since in order to use the properties of the zir and zsr solutions I need to have some expression for the solution itself but I don't have such a thing.
I don't have work to show as I'm completely overwhelmed by this question and don't know how to start.

To each differential equation, the initial conditions must be associated, which are missing here. It can then be assumed that they are all zero, so the search for a solution is simplified, but this is a special case because in general the initial conditions are not zero. The solution that is found is the forced response of the system. To simplify everything, it is convenient to apply the Laplace transformation to the right and left. In this way the differential equation is transformed into an algebraic equation in Y(s) and X(s). Y(s)=W(s)X(s), where W(s) is the transfer function of the system.

@FrancescoM. A system with all initial conditions equal to zero and a forcing function applied to its input will still have a natural response different from zero. The zero-input response, however, will be zero.

Look for similar questions on mathematics and digital signal processing stack exchanges. I'm sure there's more than one that will cover what you're looking for there.

Firstly, a bit about notation. To represent the differential equation
$$\ddot{y}(t)+a_1\dot{y}(t)+a_0y(t) = b_1\dot{x_1}(t) +b_0x(t) \tag1$$
we can make use of differential operators, letting \$D = \frac{d}{dt} \$. With this, we have
$$(D^2+a_1D+a_0)y(t) = (b_1D+b_0)x(t) \tag2$$
And generally
$$Q(D)y(t) = P(D)x(t) \tag3$$
Theorem

The total response of a system that possesses the decomposition property can be written as the sum of a zero-state response and zero-input response \$y(t) = y_{zs}(t) + y_{zi}(t)\$. Any linear system possesses the decomposition property.

Proof
Let \$y(t)\$ be the output of the system, and \$x(t)\$ the input. Let \$y(t)\$ be the solution to the initial value problem
$$Q(D)y(t) = P(D)x(t), \: \: \: y(0^-)=y_{0^-}, Dy(0^-)=y'_{0^-},... \tag4$$
Define now the zero-input response as the solution to the initial value problem
$$Q(D)y_{zi}(t) = 0, \: \: \:  y_{zi}(0^-) = y_{0^-}, Dy_{zi}(0^-) = y'_{0^-},... \tag5$$
Define also the zero-state response as the solution to the initial value problem
$$Q(D)y_{zs}(t) = P(D)x(t), \: \: \:  y_{zs}(0^-) = 0, Dy_{zs}(0^-) =0,... \tag6$$
To show that \$y(t) = y_{zs}(t) + y_{zi}(t)\$ is true we need to show that they solve the same initial value problem. Let's insert \$y(t) = y_{zs}(t) + y_{zi}(t)\$ into (3).
$$\begin{align*}Q(D)[y_{zs}(t) + y_{zi}(t)] &= P(D)x(t) \\
Q(D)y_{zs}(t) + Q(D)y_{zi}(t) &= P(D)x(t) \\
Q(D)y_{zs}(t) &= P(D)x(t)\end{align*} \tag7$$
We see, that \$[y_{zs}(t)+y_{zi}(t)]\$ and \$y(t)\$ solve the same differential equation (3). Do they also satisfy the same initial conditions?
$$y(0^-) = [y_{zs}(0^-) + y_{zi}(0^-)] = y_{zi}(0^-) = y_{0^-}\\
Dy(0^-) = D[y_{zs}(0^-) + y_{zi}(0^-)] = Dy_{zi}(0^-) = y'_{0^-}\\
... \tag8$$
Yes, they do. So \$[y_{zs}(t)+y_{zi}(t)]\$ and \$y(t)\$ solve the same differential equation and they satisfy the same initial conditions. According the existence and uniqueness theorem this implies that \$[y_{zs}(t)+y_{zi}(t)]\$ and \$y(t)\$ is the same and only solution to the initial value problem in (4).
Note that the only assumption about the system was linearity. We need not constrict ourselves to time-invariance or causality.

im sorry but I don't quite understand what you did, you removed the sum and the coefficient on each side of the system and instead put a function (Q or P) that takes as input the derivative operator itself? I don't understand what it means.

@Nate3384 That’s my fault. I assumed you were familiar with the notation in my answer. Q(D) and P(D) are operator polynomials that “operate” on functions, in this case differentiating them. I can elaborate further later today, unless others have posted an answer you think is sufficient.

@Nate3384 I've updated my answer. Maybe it's more enlightening now.

thanks! it's completely clear now!
I appreciate this greatly

A linear and stationary system with an input described by x(t) and an output y(t), is described by a non-homogeneous linear differential equation with constant coefficients or mathematical model of the system and is of the following type: not necessarily zero:

